ログイン画面のレイアウトが頻繁に変わる場合の自動ログインの方法
実行環境
ChromeOSのcrostini上のDebian
Selenium4を使用
Pythonの仮想環境はvenv
期待値
Instagramのログイン画面のうち、すべてのレイアウトのログイン画面でスムーズに自動ログインすること。
備考
ログインボタンの位置を始め、ログイン画面のデザイン自体が頻繁に変わります。
アクセスする毎に異なっていることもあるくらいです。
再現手順
下のコードを実行。
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from time import sleep

USERNAME = "xxxxxxxxxx"
PASSWORD = XXXXXXXXXX

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
target_url = "https://www.instagram.com/"
driver.get(target_url)
sleep(3)

error_flg = False
is_error_occurred = False

try:
    log_in = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//section/main/div[1]/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div/div/div[1]")
    log_in.submit()
    sleep(1)
except NoSuchElementException:
    print("要素が見つかりませんでした。レイアウトが変更されている可能性があります。")
if not is_error_occurred:
    try:
        username_input = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//input[@aria-label='Phone number, username, or email']")
        username_input.send_keys(USERNAME)
        sleep(1)

        password_input = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//input[@aria-label='Password']")
        password_input.send_keys(PASSWORD)
        sleep(1)

        login_button = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//button[@type='submit']")
        login_button.submit()
        sleep(1)
    except Exception:
        error_flg = True
        print("ユーザー名・パスワード入力時に、エラーが発生しました。")


恐らくレイアウトが頻繁に変わるのはスクレイピング対策と思われます。
スクレイピングではなく API の利用をまずは検討すべきだと思います。
少し古い記事ですが、こちらも参照してください。
https://about.fb.com/ja/news/2021/04/how-we-combat-scraping/

'24/9/17現在のInstagramの利用規約には下記記述があり

不正な方法を用いて、アカウントの作成、情報へのアクセス、または情報の取得を試みることは禁止されています。
これには、弊社から明示的な許可を得ることなく、自動化された手段を用いてアカウントを作成したり、情報を取得したりする行為が含まれます。

質問さんがやりたい事

期待値
Instagramのログイン画面のうち、すべてのレイアウトのログイン画面でスムーズに自動ログインすること。

は禁止行為に当たる可能性が高いかと思われます。
※もしもMeta社から許可を得られているのであればその旨質問文に追記ください。
